# Python : call a function with return from other function

Tags: python

I have two functions that I want to call one after the other. The return from  the first one should be the argument of the second. 
I don't find the way to do it .

```
BOARD= [[0]*10]*10

def right (board , start, n):
    board[start[0]]= [0]*start[1] + [1]*(n-start[1])
    endpoint= [start[0], start[1]+n]
    return board , endpoint , n

def down (board, start, n): 
    for j in range (1,n ):
        board[start[1]+j][start[0]]= 1
        endpoint= [start[0]+n, start[1]]
    return board , endpoint , n

# the call 
down(right(BOARD, [0,0],10))
```

the error is :  **TypeError: down() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'start' and 'n' ***

If someone has an idea please .... 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `down(*right(BOARD, [0,0],10))` -- unpacking

Comment: cool thank you very much :)

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/3001761)

Comment: As @jonrsharpe was saying, multiplying references to immutable numbers is fine, `[0]*10`, but to mutable lists is a bad idea. Try something like `[[0]*10 for _ in range(10)]` instead.